# How to group by multiple column and perform difference operation and and match the nearest value of column from difference

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to get a result which comprises grouping  3 rows and try to minus specific value with a column and try to extract a column value from with minimum difference with the specific column.
ex:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and explain with words how you want to arrive at the lower table. It looks like the data is sorted by column A. But what logic leads to an expected result of 20???

Comment: I understood this as "find the row that has, for each unique group defined by columns A and B, the minimum absolute difference between the value in column C and the "fixed value" outside of the table, then return the value from column D for that row"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary you can:

1. Convert your range to a Table
2. Create a name for the cell that holds the "Value"
3. Add a column that subtracts the Value from column C
4. Add a column that compares the MIN of step 3 for each of the groups defined by columns A and B and flags the expected result
5. Add a column that returns the value from column D if the flag is TRUE
6. Combine steps 3, 4 and 5 into a single formula instead :)

So, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to convert to a Table:

[image]

Create a named cell for the value:

[image]

Add a column to calculate the absolute difference between C and the_value:

```
=ABS([@C]-the_value)
```

[image]

Add a column that compares the MIN of D from each group to the current row D:

```
=MINIFS([Diff],[A],[@A],[B],[@B])=[@Diff]
```

[image]

Add a column that returns the value from column D if the flag is TRUE:

```
=IF([@[Min Diff in Group]],[@D],"")
```

[image]

Combine steps 3, 4 and 5 into a single formula instead:

```
=IF(MINIFS([Diff],[A],[@A],[B],[@B])=ABS([@C]-the_value),[@D],"")
```

[image]

EDIT: if you have a version of Excel earlier than 2019, you won't have MINIFS. You can achieve the same thin using an array formula. In this case, **don't** use an Excel Table (step 1). Use a normal range.

In this case, the "Min Diff in Group" column mentioned above would use this formula:

```
{=MIN(IF((Sheet1!$A$5:$A$10=Sheet1!$A5)*(Sheet1!$B$5:$B$10=Sheet1!$B5),Sheet1!$E$5:$E$10))=Sheet1!$E5}
```

Note that while with a normal formula you would press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering it in the cell, with an array formula, you must finish entering it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is how you tell earlier versions of Excel that your formula contains arrays or Ranges of cells.

The formula from Column G would remain unchanged from above.

The formula for the "All together" column, would become this:

```
{=IF(MIN(IF((Sheet1!$A$5:$A$10=Sheet1!$A5)*(Sheet1!$B$5:$B$10=Sheet1!$B5),Sheet1!$E$5:$E$10))=Sheet1!$E5,Sheet1!$D5,"")}
```

Again, this must be entered as an array formula, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answere but I m not able to perform =MINIFS([Diff],[A],[@A],[B],[@B])=[@Diff] this step can you help me with this

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I m using Excel 2007

Comment: Please see my post edit. If you're able to get this working, please consider upvoting and accepting my answer.